# How to export 'simplified' geometry from Simulation workspace in Fusion 360 to ANSYS Mechanical?

Tags: structural-analysis, simulation, ansys, meshing

I would like to export the *defeatured* version of my design to ANSYS.

I tried adopting the following methods but they weren't working out.

1. (https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/fusion-360-design-validate/how-to-export-model-after-simulation-simplify/td-p/7360686) - After simplification, I tried copying (Ctrl+C) from the existing design to a new file (Ctrl+V) which didn't seem to work.
   (Tried copying from the 'Model components' in the browser and pasting it into the browser in the new empty design. It did seem to load but failed in the end)
2. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K28y5a2ortM)- I also tried exporting the simulation study as a **.sdz** file using the ANSYS plugin. However, the ACT wizard in ANSYS failed to open it.

The structure to be analysed is quite big and I am not in favour of defeaturing in SpaceClaim.

Please do share a workaround for this problem.

Thank you.

Comment: What filetype is common?

Comment: .sdz file that is exported from Fusion contains the entire simulation study setup inside the simulation workspace. Ideally, this should be accessible using ANSYS after the 'ExternalStudyImporter' extension has been enabled.

Comment: Would you have a picture of the 3D? The best extensions to be imported in Ansys APDL are `.x_t` and `.igs`. I have expercienced many glitches with other extensions.